# href with onclick javascript pop-up

Tags: php, javascript, html, popup, href

i have this javascript:

```
<SCRIPT LANGUAGE="JavaScript">
<!-- 

// Generated at http://www.csgnetwork.com/puhtmlwincodegen.html 
function popUp(URL) {
day = new Date();
id = day.getTime();
eval("page" + id + " = window.open(URL, '" + id + "', 'toolbar=0,scrollbars=0,location=0,statusbar=0,menubar=0,resizable=0,width=500,height=400,left = 283,top = -16');");

}

// -->
</script>
```

i want to use an href with a javascript popup function but its not working.
here is my code

```
 <?php
    echo "<a href = '#' onClick='javascript:popUp('editdelete.php?emoticon_text=$emoticon_text&id=$id')'><img src='update.png'></a>";
    ?>
```

but its not working

(the $emoticon_text and the $id will be passed to the pop up window using $_GET function.)

thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are mixing your quotes usage.  Please try the following:

```
<a href = '#' onClick='javascript:popUp("editdelete.php?emoticon_text=$emoticon_text&id=$id")'><img src='update.png'></a>
```

Note the double quotes inside `javascript:popUp` inplace of single quote as you have in your question.

**Update:**

After OP's comment below:

```
<?php echo "<a href = '#' onClick='javascript:popUp(\'editdelete.php?emoticon_text=$emoticon_text&id=$id\')'‌​><img src='update.png'></a>"; ?>
```

Comment: uhmm they are inside the an 
<?php
echo "<a href = '#' onClick='javascript:popUp('editdelete.php?emoticon_text=$emoticon_text&id=$id')'><img src='update.png'></a>";
?>

Comment: @ChristianBurgos, in that case you might need to escape the quotes with `\`, please post your full line.

Answer (score 0):

```
<a href = '#' onClick='javascript:popUp('editdelete.php?emoticon_text=$emoticon_text&id=$id')'><img src='update.png'></a>
```

should be

```
<a href = '#' onClick="javascript:popUp('editdelete.php?emoticon_text=<?php echo $emoticon_text; ?>&id=<?php echo $id; ?>')"><img src='update.png'></a>
```